# Appending node to LinkedList

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that adds a node to the end of a LinkedList. I know how to do it using loops, but my professor wants it done a certain way and I don't understand why it's not working. He practically gave us all the code for it..

This is the pseudo-code he gave us:

```
process append(data) 
  if (not the end)
     next->append(data);

  else
     next=new Node();
     next->data=data;
     next->data = nullptr;
```

And this is what I came up with:

```
struct Node {

int data;
Node* next;


};

struct LinkedList {
  Node* head;

  LinkedList() {head = nullptr;}

 void prepend(int data) {

  if (head == nullptr) {

       Node* tmp = new Node();
       tmp->data=data;
       tmp->next=nullptr;

}

  else  {

    Node* tmp = new Node();
    tmp->data=data;
    tmp->next=head;
    head=tmp;


  }
}

  void append(int data) {

  Node* tmp = head;

     if (tmp->next != nullptr) {

        tmp=tmp->next->append(data);

 }

else {

    tmp->next = new Node();
    tmp->next->data = data;
    tmp->next->next = nullptr;


    }


  }
};





int main()
{
    LinkedList LL = LinkedList();
    LL.prepend(7);
    LL.append(6);
    std::cout << LL.head->data << std::endl;
}
```

My prepend (to add to the beginning of the LinkedList) works fine, but when I try this code, I get

main.cpp:48:20: error: 'struct Node' has no member named 'append'
tmp->next->append(data);

So I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong with saying next->append(data), which from what I understood, is supposed to be recursively calling back the append function until it reaches a nullpointer. I'm thinking maybe there's some sort of way to write it, but people in my class are telling me that the next->append(data) thing SHOULD work, so I guess I'm not exactly sure why this isn't doing anything. I tried instead writing the append function in the Node struct, but then it says that head wasn't declared in the scope and I really just don't know how to work with this. I'm also sort of new to classes/structs in C++ so I'm assuming it's something about that that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Node` has not any method named `append` so you get that error message:

```
tmp->next->append(data);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

struct Node {

int data;
Node* next;

};
```

To append a node to a linked-list, you don't need an `append` method within `Node`. Remove that. Correct the append process in `LinkedList::append`:

```
void append(int data) {

 Node* tmp = head;

 while (tmp->next)
     tmp = tmp->next;


  tmp->next = new Node();
  tmp->next->data = data;
  tmp->next->next = nullptr;
}
```

I did't test, but you need something like above code. At first, it tries to access to the end of list. Then it appends a node.

---

Recursive implementation:

```
void append(int data) {

   append(data, head);
}

void append(int data, Node *node) {

   if (node->next)
       append(data, node->next);
   else {
    tmp->next = new Node();
    tmp->next->data = data;
    tmp->next->next = nullptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured it was something related to that, but I didn't know how to fix it. I just put void append(int) inside the Node struct but that didn't do anything so I'm assuming that's now how you do it.

Comment: I know how to do this with loops though, I think he wants the function to call itself so that it can move from node to node checking if the next one is pointing to null

Comment: @FrostyStraw: I just updated and added a new implementation, It's a bit different but it's recursive.

Comment: Should it be if (node -> next != nullptr) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your append method isn't defined on the Struct Node. Instead it's defined on the LinkedList class so you need to invoke it accordingly. You can redefine the append method to take a node as a parameter or add an append method to the Struct Node itself. Also there's no need to assign the result of append to `tmp =`

Your append method is void.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
struct Node
{
    void append(int data)
    {
        if (next)
            next->append(data);
        else
        {
            next = new Node();
            next->data = data;
            next->next= nullptr;
        }
    }
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

it's clear from the pseudo code `next->append(data);` that append is meant to be a member of `Node`.

Here's how you might use `Node::append` from `LinkedList::append`

```
class LinkedList {
    void append(int data) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new Node();
            head->data=data;
            head->next=nullptr;
        }
        else {
            head->append(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I'm pretty sure it'll tell me that head was not declared in that scope.. But I will try

Comment: @FrostyStraw But you don't need head in Node::append, nor is head in the pseudo code you've been given. Maybe the problem is that you don't understand the pseudo code?

Comment: @FrostyStraw I've modified my answer to include the correct code. My code is the same as the pseudo code, your code was a bit different for some reason.

Comment: I don't understand how it will just...know what "next" is pointing to if I haven't made it start from the beginning (or the head). I can't just put next without something preceding it like he did in the code, can I?

Comment: Node has a member called next, just like LinkedList has a member called head. It's no different.

Comment: Yeah, but head is pointing to null because of the constructor. I feel like next...doesn't point to anything until you make it with the append...okay, I'm sort of confused as to what exactly I'm confused about (-_-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be next->next=nullptr? I'm also getting a seg fault now

Comment: Yes you are right, next->next = nullptr, sorry about that. The segfault is because of a bug somewhere else in your code. Probably you are *using* append incorrectly.

Comment: To maybe better explain my confusion, I'm saying that the "next" member of the Node won't actually be pointing at anything until a node is actually created (which occurs in the prepend function), and as a result, I feel like those "nexts" aren't really doing anything unless there are nodes created and head is pointing to those nodes, which is why I was using head in my code.

Comment: @FrostyStraw Obviously Node::next doesn't point to anything until the node is created. But equally you cannot call Node::append on a node which hasn't been created. I think you're confusing the purpose of Node::append, by itself it does not append a node to your list, if that were it's purpose it would be a member of LinkedList not a member of Node. Node::append is a *helper function* that will help you write the append function for a LinkedList. But you still have to write the append function for a LinkedList yourself, and that will involve using LinkedList::head.

Comment: I'm guessing that's what my professor meant when he said " your LinkedList class/struct must support void append(int data) while your node shall implement all necessary operations necessary to support the LinkedList functions" ?But I'm looking at the Node::append function that I have (and that you also have), and it looks like it takes care of the creation of the node right there. So

Comment: if that's already creating a node right there, I really don't understand how to like...actually use head anywhere. I don't get how to relate the function append when it's in two different structs

Comment: @FrostyStraw See updated answer, but note I haven't tested anything, so apologies for any errors. The answer to your question is that you call Node::append from LinkedList::append using the head pointer.

Comment: @FrostyStraw BTW I just noticed the prepend function you posted above is bugged, were you aware of that?

Comment: @FrostyStraw Exactly. It could also be simplified, look at the differences between the if part and the else part, they're not much, you don't really need and if ... else at all.

Comment: Also, if I'm finally understanding correctly, I'm guessing when you do head->append(data) after you've actually created the first node, it does "append" on what head is pointing to (a node), which is why I needed to have the function in both node and LinkedList? Sounds like the answer is obvious but I feel like understanding this is a big breakthrough lol

Comment: @FrostyStraw Yes, and if head happened to be pointing at a sequence of two nodes, it would append at after the second node (because Node::append walks along the sequence of Nodes until it finds the last one). Personally I would not have chosen to do things as your professor has chosen, I would have put everything in LinkedList and had Node as just a simple struct. But that's program design for you, everyone has a different opinion.

Comment: He made us do it both ways. I did it correctly when I had Node as just a simple struct (which I'm assuming means it just has next and data and no actual functions in it), but he also wanted it done this way.

Answer (score 0):

tmp->next is a Node, so to call append function, you must declare it in Node struct

Answer (score 0):

The node structure does not contain any append method.
Moreover, you are splitting work that can be done in one methos to two methods, writing more code.

See my answer to another question here with working code I wrote

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358192/6341507

As you can see, I solve all in method

```
AddItem(int i)
```

I start seeing that creating linked list i kindof har for many people here, so I will further edit my answer there to provide additional information.

Good luck!